# Does the shape of a volume affects the force applied on the object based on Archimede's principle

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, drag, buoyancy, viscosity

Does the shape of a volume affects the force applied on the object based on Archimede's principle?

1. Does the shape of the volume affects the force in any way. For instance, will a helium balloon that has an arrow shape would rise faster than a sphere, for a same volume?
2. If the Archimede's principle force is not affected by the shape. Would anything else affect the speed of ascent? Friction?

Comment: You title and part of the text ask about the buoyant force. Other parts of your text ask about speed of ascent. At times it looks like you understand that these are different concepts and at other times like you are conflating them somewhat. They are distinct.

Comment: Well the higher the buoyant force, the faster the ascent. Those are related.

Comment: @Sylvain: Consider them separately. Consider buoyant force as what would be measured if you tether the balloon to a scale. Consider ascent speed as a matter of aerodynamic drag versus velocity.

Comment: What do you think the answers are?

Comment: @sammygerbil I don't know. Intuitively I would think the shape influence the buoyant force, but nowhere does it say this in the Archimede formula. That's why I asked, but then I realised if I am interested in the ascent speed there got to be other forces that apply, other than the buoyant force.

Comment: Why the downgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Although the shape does not alter the magnitude of the force due to Archimede's principle, it determines where the center of mass of the object is.

A counter-acting and distinct force is air resistance. This works against buoyancy, and can reduce acceleration. A more streamlined shape oriented upwards will rise faster.

2. Density of the object, which will include any gas it contains. Increasing the temperature of that gas reduces its density. Selecting light molecules, Hydrogen. Helium. If the density of the surrounding fluid or gas is higher it will rise faster.